# rows with create/update date, calculate pending count with mysql sliding window?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, rolling-computation, sliding-window

I have a mysql table like

```
create table items(
  id primary key,
  content varchar,
  created_at datetime,
  updated_at datetime
)
```

Now each row was inserted with a `created_at` but without `updated_at`, we call this row "pending". After a user update the `content` the `updated_at` field is modified.

I need to calculate the number of "pending" rows for every hour within a given start/end date. I tried with sliding window but failed. I think the aggregation need some kind of preceding counter to start with? Any ideas? TIA.

Comment: if an hour between start & end does not have records, show zero or don't show the record? and if start/end are at different date, same hours combine or show as different rows, sample data and expected result will help.

Comment: @ProGu The "pending" count should be the sum of unedited rows, thus zero, naturally.